# How do I evaluate the terms in an expression, but not the expression itself?

Tags: evaluation

I am trying to write a set of homework questions.

I would like the output to evaluate the constants but not the sum, so that I may present the homework question as something like this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{340}(-4n^2-n+3)$$

Here's what I have:

```
c1 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
c2 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
c3 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
c4 = RandomInteger[{1, 50}]*20
f[x_] := c1*x^2 + c2*x + c3 
f[n] 
(* 340
   3 - n - 4 n^2 *)

Defer[Sum[f[n], {n, 1, c4}]]
```

$\sum _{n=1}^{\text{c4}} f(n)$

It seems like I am not using `Defer` correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to make sure that `f` and `c4` are evaluated. This can be done in several ways, one of which was shown by Mark. Another equally valid approach is to use `With` to inject the evaluated form inside the held expression:

```
With[{f = f[n], c4 = c4}, Defer[Sum[f, {n, 1, c4}]]]
```

Comment: i would bump up your answer if I could.. but I need better reputation.  thank you rm-rf  thx for your help.. much appreciated

Comment: Everyone has their favorite approach, although, I note that `Evaluate` doesn't work here.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Although I usually use `With`, I almost posted an answer that was exactly the same as yours when you submitted it... so I scrapped it and went ahead with `With` :) Btw, what did you mean re: `Evaluate`?

Comment: Oftentimes, `Evaluate` is used for this sort of thing, e.g. `Plot[Evaluate[list],___]`, where `list` might involve a `Table` or some such. In this problem, you can't wrap `Evaluate` around the `f[n]`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yeah, `Evaluate` won't work in this case because it is too deep in the expression.

Answer (score 8):

Defer blocks evaluation of the entire input expression, so `f[n]` stays as `f[n]`.  You want to evaluate certain subparts of the expression but not the whole thing.  One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
Defer[Sum[#1, {n, 1, #2}]]&[f[n], c4]
```

or, if you want traditional ordering of the polynomial,

```
Defer[Sum[#1, {n, 1, #2}]] &[TraditionalForm[f[n]], c4]
```

The first part (up to and including the ampersand `&`) is a pure function of two variables.  The rest indicates that you're plugging `f[n]` and `c4` into that function.  Since they initially lie outside the scope of `Defer`, they are evaluated to what you want and then plugged in.

Comment: thank you Mark! that works beautifully, thank you, thank you! If I may.. one more question, is there a way to force printing of polynomial in descending order?

Comment: @userX See edit.

Comment: i would bump up your answer if I could.. but I need better reputation.

Comment: perfect! thank you both, much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

A few additional methods for you to chew on:

```
Block[{Defer, Sum},
  Sum[f[n], {n, 1, c4}] // Defer
]

Block[{Sum},
  Defer @@ {Sum[f[n], {n, 1, c4}]}
]

Composition[Defer, Sum] @@ {f[n], {n, 1, c4}}

Defer @ Sum @ ## & @@ {f[n], {n, 1, c4}}
```

Each produces:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with `// TraditionalForm`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for rm-rf's approach. Since that's taken though:

```
expr = Defer[Sum[f[n], {n, 1, c4}]];
ReplacePart[expr, # -> expr[[Sequence @@ #]]] &@{1, 1}
```

(but use `With`, not this).